# Specific problem passing javascript variable from work.php page to index.php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hey guys I have this page work.php with html and javascript codes and the form refers to index.php page. Also I am trying to pass the variable counter from my javascript to the index.php page. It's not working at all. Can you please have a look? I can't seem to figure out the issue.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id=parent_div>
<button  type="button" id="add_step" > Add step!</button>

<input type='submit' name='submit'>
<br/>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(e){


var counter=2;
function send_counter(counter) {
    $.ajax({
      url   : "index.php", 
      type  : "POST",
      cache : false,
      data  : {
        counter : counter
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

And here is my index.php page:

```
<?php



if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$counter=$_POST['counter'];
echo "$counter";

}
?>
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['submit'])` will fail as no value for `submit` is sent, try `isset($_POST['counter'])`

Comment: Ask yourself, how your `form` is connected to your `send_counter` function. Tip: its not. You might want something like [this](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Answer (score 0):

You are only passing the variables you mention in the `data` parameter

```
function send_counter(counter) {
    $.ajax({
      url   : "index.php", 
      type  : "POST",
      cache : false,
      data  : { counter : counter }
    });
  }
});
```

So only `counter` so `$_POST` will only contain that one array occurance, `$_POST['counter']`.

So change the PHP to look for that

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['counter'])){
    $counter=$_POST['counter'];
    echo "$counter";
}
?>
```

Or you could add a `submit` to the `data` object.

```
function send_counter(counter) {
    $.ajax({
      url   : "index.php", 
      type  : "POST",
      cache : false,
      data  : { counter : counter, submit: 1 }
    });
  }
});
```

and change the PHP back to

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $counter=$_POST['counter'];
    echo "$counter";
}
?>
```

Comment: But it's not working still. Does it have something to do with <form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Also, i added the </form> tag and the </html> tag at last. so the index.php page is running (i tested it with echo "Hello";) but I am not getting anything for $counter

Comment: I wonder if i am missing something really basic. i am totally new to this